# Unable to open robomongo

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I had installed **robomongo** from [robomongo link](https://robomongo.org/download) and got a **.tar.gz** file I extracted it and navigated to **bin** to open the app but could not open it this did not throw me an error anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. you can use the older version of robomongo instead of robomongo 3T ([download older version](https://download.robomongo.org/1.0.0/linux/robomongo-1.0.0-linux-x86_64-89f24ea.tar.gz)).

There not much huge difference between these version.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue but saw this fix use these steps to get it to work:

```
mkdir ~/robo-backup
mv robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/lib/libstdc++* ~/robo-backup/
robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin/robo3t
```

Source:

https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1385